# CKeditor via CDN optional plugins

Tags: wysiwyg, cdn

The latest Drupal Ckeditor Module 1.14 loads the Ckeditor library via CDN.
The table on http://ckeditor.com/presets-all shows the 5 possible packages to be used via CDN.
I am using the Full-all package.
This package has a lot of optional plugins.

How can I activate these optional Ckeditor plugins in Drupal ????

Answer (score 0):

In the CKEditor profile area if I am hearing you correctly:

> admin/config/content/ckeditor